# Multitexturing problem (newbie)

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I am new to the OpenGL and mobile programming in general.

I am trying to load 2 textures and show them on one object (I mean one set of vercicles) with different coordinates.

My approach:

```
glGenTextures(2, &textures[0]);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glClientActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, mapTextCoords);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, map.width, map.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [map getByteData]);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glClientActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1 );
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, backgroundTextCoords);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, background.width, background.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [background getByteData]);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, mapVertices);
```

What am I doing wrong? And what should I do next?

```
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, BYTES_PER_PIXEL);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
```

In result i got white object (no textures at all).

Answer (score 2):

Try providing a complete set of mipmaps if you're going to use `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`'s [default](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture) of `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

Or set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST`/`GL_LINEAR`.

Answer (score 0):

For initializing, try:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texA);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texA);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_t, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lod, GL_RGB, pixWidth, pixHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixelData);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Modify the above as needed for your particular needs, and repeat for the 2nd texture.

For drawing, try:

```
// Bind textures
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+i);        // set which texture unit will be affected by subsequent glBindTexture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texA);    // bind a 2D texture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+i);        // set a different texture unit than above
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texB);    // bind another 2D texture

// Set texcoords for first texture
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+i);  // set which texture unit will be affected by subsequent
                                       // call to glTexCoordPointer (should match what you
                                       // gave glActiveTexture for texA earlier)
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  // enable texcoord attributes
glTexCoordPointer(...);                // pass the texcoord array for texA

// Set texcoords for second texture
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+i);  // set which texture unit will be affected by subsequent
                                       // call to glTexCoord pointer (should match what you
                                       // gave glActiveTexture for texB earlier)
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(...);    // pass the texcoord array for texB
```

**Note**: Don't do what you're doing by passing `GL_TEXTURE1`, `GL_TEXTURE2`, etc., but rather pass `GL_TEXTURE0+i` where *i* is a value between 0 and the implementation-specific result of `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_COORDS`.